# What happens to answers that are "not an answer"?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

I was reviewing the *First posts* queue a few minutes ago, and I found an "answer" which was clearly not an answer. The typical "I have a similar problem [...] please help me". However, in this case the user had added something like this at the end of his "answer":

> PS: sorry for posting this as an answer, given that both problems are related, it just made more sense to ask it here instead of opening a new thread.

He posted it wrong, but he was well intended.

I flagged it as *not an answer*, but before doing so, I spent a couple of minutes to leave him a comment, explaining nicely that this is not a forum with "threads" but a Q&A site, and asking him to please remove his "answer" and post it as a new question instead.

Just a few minutes after that, I've seen that my flag has been "helpful". If I reopen the question, the "answer" is not there anymore... and obviously, the comment is gone too.

So here is my doubt: **what happens when an answer is *not an answer*?** Does it get deleted? Is the poster still able to see it, and/or read the comments he received? Does he at least get a notification, message, whatever, explaining what happened to his message?

Comment: [as described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), "deleted questions and answers that were posted in the past 90 days, can be seen using..." See also: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/165773)

Comment: So: yes, they get deleted, but no, leaving a comment is not a waste of time - the user is still able to read them... if he knows where to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `flag` it as *this is not an answer* -- but also leaving a comment for the user is good etiquette and helpful to educate the user..

Once it is flagged it will eventually get to the review queue for a quorum to decide on the faith of the non-answer, and it will eventually get deleted if not deleted by the user first.

Comment: I was (until I read gnat's comment) mostly concerned about the fact that the user might not even get the chance to read the comments, if the flag is processed "too fast", like it happened yesterday